# a reusable query with modifications?

Tags: php, mysql, code-reuse

i'm using this mysql query alongwith php to search for multiple keywords:

```
$query = "SELECT cQuotes, vAuthor, cArabic, vReference FROM ".$table." WHERE (";
  $countFields = count($arrayFields);
  while ($a < $countFields)
  {
    while ($b < $countSearch)
    {
      $query = $query."$arrayFields[$a] LIKE '%$arraySearch[$b]%'";
      $b++;
      if ($b < $countSearch)
      {
        $query = $query." AND ";
      }
    }
    $b = 0;
    $a++;
    if ($a < $countFields)
    {
      $query = $query.") OR (";
    }
  }
  $query = $query.")";
  $result = mysql_query($query, $conn)
```

i'd like to reuse this query with a few modifications to it (for instance, the WHERE clause remains the same, while i query the number of rows using COUNT), but it doesn't seem practical to repeat the code again for a few additions. any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand **exactly** what you're doing since there's code missing, but I'd suggest the following:

Don't use while with arrays; use foreach it's much more compact and that's what it was made for.

Don't concatenate strings manually, use implode()

Don't add complexity to your SQL to count result; use MYSQL's FOUND_ROWS() instead.

On a somewhat unrelated note I'd suggest upgrading from PHP's mysql library to mysqli. It allows multiple queries, which will make your life easier.

Comment: i've been trying to implement paging to the search results, but it isn't working out. some paging tutorials suggest using COUNT, while i've seen some using mysql_num_rows to calculate the number of rows.

Comment: @fusion - If you have problems with PHP/MySQL pagination specifically, you might want to post a new question just for that.

Comment: using found_rows enforces you to do the query then get the number of returned rows. using count will just return the count. Which is nicer to the server specially if you are selecting many rows.

Comment: @Yousf - COUNT is a pain if you're using LIMIT for pagination (and you should). It forces you to run the query once without LIMIT to get the count and again with LIMIT to get the subset of results you want. FOUND_ROWS will return the total number of results regardless of LIMIT, which makes it perfect for pagination as it eliminates the need to rerun the query.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$table = "myTable";
$justCount = true;
$requiredFields = array('cQuotes', 'vAuthor', 'cArabic', 'vReference');
$arrayFields = array('cQuotes','vAuthor');
$arraySearch = array('blah','foo','bar');

///////////////
$selectWhat = $justCount ? "COUNT(*)" : implode(',', $requiredFields);

$wherePart = array();
foreach($arraySearch as $search)
{
    $subWherePart = array();
            foreach($arrayFields as $field)
    {
        $subWherePart[] = $field . " LIKE '%" . $search ."%'";
    }
    $wherePart[] = "(" . implode(" AND ", $subWherePart) . ")";
}

$query = "SELECT " . $selectWhat . " FROM " . $table
        . " WHERE " . implode(" OR ", $wherePart);

?>
```

don't forget to filter input search words to avoid SQL Injection.

Answer (score 1):

You could pull that code out into a separate function, then send it a parameter telling the function what version of the query you want.  The function would then construct the query and return the string.  I also think prepared statements might be beneficial to you.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a query builder library or ORM, especially if this problem is happening repeatedly. They allow you to create SQL functionally. I would suggest using [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) or [Sqloo](http://github.com/softwareelves/Sqloo) (spoiler alert: I'm the creator of Sqloo). Since you can use them to functionally create SQL, you can even pass partial queries around since they object, to allow for a very high reuse of code.

A few examples for [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/2_0/en/query-builder) and [Sqloo](http://github.com/softwareelves/Sqloo/blob/master/example/result_test.php).